# Make directory junction (symlink) equivalent to mklink /j

Tags: php, symbolic-link

I am developing a web application with php in windows environment and I am using symlink to avoid redundancy. I made the symlinks with mklink /j command using exec(). Today I decided to test the app in linux and I used 'ln -s' command. But the app malfunctioned and can't find files correctly. So what is the equivalent of directory junctions in linux?

Comment: NTFS has symbolic links which work exactly as Unix symbolic links, but `mklink /j` creates a junction point, not a symbolic link. An NTFS junction is much more similar to a Unix mountpoint, and it is actually represented as a mountpoint internally. Use  `mount --bind` in Linux to emulate the behavior of an NTFS junction.

Comment: that worked for me. thanks. i just needed to make the directory in the target link. pls add it as an answer :)

Comment: All right, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NTFS has symbolic links which work exactly as Unix symbolic links, but `mklink /j` creates a junction point, not a symbolic link.

An NTFS junction is much more similar to a Unix mountpoint, and it is actually represented as a mountpoint internally. Use `mount --bind` in Linux to emulate the behavior of an NTFS junction.

Comment: with problems that mounting has caused me (when the mounted directory is removed without umount the source would be removed as well) I decided to use `ln -s` recursively or `cp -s`

Comment: so what's actually difference as both just works almost impossibly distinguishable from a user?

Comment: @cantikmemekmu: Junctions and symlinks are very different internally; from the point of view of a user, the main difference is that junctions have been available since the beginning of time, whereas symlinks are relatively new (introduced with Windows Vista). For the gritty details, see "[What is the difference between NTFS Junction Points and Symbolic Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542)" on Stack Overflow.